# Retornar nomes que não tenham oficina cadastrada

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, pl-sql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, Gostaria de uma ajuda para retornar nomes que não contenham a oficina'2' no caso cadastrada.
Da forma que montei, ele me traz diferente de (''), preciso que além de diferente, me traga os que não possuem tal oficina cadastrada.

Exemplo me mostra todos com a oficina 1 cadastrada, mas quem está na 1 não necessariamente tem a 2 cadastrada em seu usuário.

```
SELECT /*usu.rowid,*/
       db.cd_usuario,
       db.nm_usuario ,
       usu.cd_oficina
       FROM Usuarios_Oficina_Funcao usu,
            usuarios db
            WHERE usu.cd_oficina NOT IN ('2','3','4','5','6','7','8')
            AND   usu.cd_usuario NOT IN ('USUARIO')
            AND   usu.cd_usuario (+)   = db.cd_usuario
            ORDER BY cd_usuario
```

** Na imagem, o usuário ADRIANA.SANTOS tem a oficina 1 e 2 cadastrada, mas o usuário ADRIELY.SANTOS possui somente a oficina 1.
Eu preciso que me traga somente que não tem a oficina 2 cadastrada, da forma que exemplifiquei, me trouxe somente os valores diferentes dos que estão em ().
Obrigado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: *"ele me traz diferente de ('')*" onde está isso na query? não ficou claro.  *"que não contenham a oficina'2'"* isso está na query, está meio confuso, coloque na pergunta exemplos de dados das 2 tabelas e do resultado, olhando para  a query o `NOT IN` já filtra isso

Comment: Adicionei mais informações a pergunta.

Comment: cd_oficina não é number? se for não precisa por aspas nos valores, pelo resultado parece ser... se for mesmo texto, se não for **exatamente** `'2'` pode não filtrar, se tive por exemplo algum espaço

Comment: Tentou um NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: Em relação as aspas não está influenciando, pois está filtrando certo. O NOT EXISTS  não me trouxe retorno, mas ficaria desta forma?                                                              SELECT 
       db.cd_usuario,
       db.nm_usuario ,
       usu.cd_oficina
       FROM Usuarios_Oficina_Funcao usu,
                  dbasgu.usuarios db
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Usuarios_Oficina_Funcao o WHERE o.cd_oficina IN ('2')  (OU = 2 também não trouxe retorno)
            AND usu.cd_usuario (+) = db.cd_usuario
            ORDER BY cd_usuario